# Qual melhor maneira de trabalhar em modo offline e sincronizar dados com servidor?

Tags: android, lado-do-servidor, sincronização

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde será necessário que os usuários façam cadastros offline e depois submetam seus cadastros para o servidor assim que a conexão com a internet estiver disponível.

Meu problema é saber:

- Qual a melhor caminho para se trabalhar em modo offline? Preferencialmente Android nativo.
- Quando 2 usuários em dispositivos diferentes realizar uma modificação nas informações de uma pessoa, como farei a atualização no servidor?

Comment: Se duas pessoas alteram o mesmo registro offline, a primeira que sincronizar deve ter a alteração aplicada enquanto que a segunda deve falhar (um número de revisão associado a cada registro pode ser usado para verificar isso).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A melhor forma de manter informações offline, no Android, é realmente o [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Mas, para a atualização no servidor, acredito que o melhor procedimento é marcar a atualização com um código de versão e um timestamp.

Assim, antes de enviar a informação para o servidor, você poderá verificar a versão da configuração e qual das versões concorrentes é a mais atual.

Você pode, também, no servidor, criar uma regra de "*merge*" de dados. Dando preferência de sobreposição para os dados mais recentes.

Outra prática que pode ser muito boa é mostrar ao usuário que há um conflito de dados e perguntar a ele qual versão deve ser mantida. Um aplicativo que usa esse método é o "Meu Malvado Favorito" (ou "Minion Rush" em inglês) da Gameloft.

Comment: Eu estava quebrando a cabeça se devia duplicar linhas com diferentes versões do mesmo item, ou tentar bolar um update, mais como quero liberdade, 1 usuário trabalhar em mais de um dispositivo ou poder ter vários usuários editando o mesmo item, seu conselho caiu bem, o jeito então é versionar tudo, e o último é o principal. um conflito será bem raro ou quase nulo, pois dificilmente os usuários editaram a mesma pessoa.

Answer (score 2):

Para se trabalhar com cadastros offline no Android deve-se utilizar o [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), um bom tutorial pode ser encontrado [aqui](http://fabrica.ms.senac.br/2013/06/criando-e-usando-banco-de-dados-em-uma-aplicacao-android/).

Nos casos de alteração do mesmo registro, o ideal é que toda vez que for detectada uma alteração em um registro desatualizado, bloquear a alteração, atualizar o registro no dispositivo com os dados novos e avisar o usuário que ele deve refazer a alteração naquele registro.

Estou assumindo que você já tem uma API responsável por gerenciar os dados enviados pelos dispositivos.

Comment: Eu até já criei uma App test, pra mim bolar as atualizações,  até tive sucesso, consegui atualizar e enviar itens novos e modificados, porém ao querer 1 CONTA em 2 dispositivos editando o mesmo item, ou 3 CONTA fazendo o mesmo, aí a coisa ficou bem mais complicada. irei considerar sua resposta, quanto ao tutorial é muito bom, mais existe um tal de Neodatis, que é um banco OO com Licença LGPL, muito bom!!!

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma SIMPLES e bastante EFICIENTE de trabalhar com dados offline e sincronização é **usar uma API de banco de dados *realtime***. Pois a própria API manterá seus dados sincronizados, mesmo offline, deixando você livre de toda complexidade de gerenciar esses dados em dois bancos diferentes.

Sugiro usar o [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), que trabalha com as principais plataformas, como Android, iOS e Web, e possui um plano grátis (máximo de conexões de 50, 5 GB transferencia de dados, 100 MB de registros no banco).

Answer (score 0):

Para o primeiro problema usar o SQLite.

O segundo problema possa ser resolvido com um Log de alterações no servidor. Ao fazer o update da informações do servidor para o aparelho, vc deverá obter o o id do ultimo registro do log junto com a informação alterável, e ao realizar a sincronização da informação alterada com o servidor, verificar se o registro de log que vc tem é igual ao ultimo registro do servidor, se sim, altera e grava um novo registro no log, se não, quer dizer que outra pessoa já fez uma alteração e incluiu um novo registro, fazendo com que o seu ultimo registro do log no aparelho seja inferior ao ultimo registro do log no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Como as respostas anteriores, utilize o SQLite para salvar no dispositivo.

[Services no Android (Documentação)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Quando a aplicação abrir, inicie um service que fará a sincronização com o servidor quando ele tiver conectividade com a internet, assim ele sincronizará automaticamente sem a necessidade do usuário interagir para enviar/receber dados.

Answer (score 0):

Em relação a primeira pergunta, uma outra alternativa de banco de dados é o [db4o](http://www.db4o.com).

É orientado a objetos, apesar da documentação um pouco fraca, é muito mais rápido e prático de utilizar do que banco relacional. Claro que existem exceções e limitações, só que acredito que vale a pena dar uma olhada e testar.

A segunda questão, não tem como fugir muito do que já foi dito anteriormente.
É necessário manter um registro da data de alteração. Assim quando tiver conexão, faça uma comparação da data de alteração, para verificar qual é mais atual.

Answer (score 0):

Em relação à segunda pergunta, poderias ter na BD um campo que, por exemplo começaria como 1.

E em offline eles fariam as alterações, e depois quando iriam online verificariam qual dos dois teria o campo maior. Se fosse o offline, então alteraria os campos, se fosse o online nada aconteceria.

Vê isto como se fosse a versão de um videojogo que utiliza um launcher. Cada vez que é iniciado, ele liga-se a BD para verificar se a versão que tem é igual a que está no BD.

E claro que quem diz com números inteiros, diz também com datas (até pode ser mais fácil rever depois a data de alteração dos dados).

Espero ter ajudado x)

Comment: MrW0lFe seja bem vindo ao StackOverflowPt. Sua resposta se parece mais como um comentário e não se adequa com o modelo do site. Que tal fazer um Tour anter de começar ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Se for dados diferentes em que apenas o id poderá gerar conflito, a solução ideal para isso é utilizar com id o modelo UUID, que gera um código que jamais irá se repetir e você não precisa se preocupar se alguém já enviou dados com o mesmo id que o seu.